# Why can't I use the .hasClass(value) method on a object HTMLImageElement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am retrieving images from my HTML using JavaScript with the following code:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

If I understand JavaScript correctly this returns an object of type HTMLImageElement. I can access it's variable directly using the .className variable but I can't call the Jquery .hasClass() method on it. Why is this?

Comment: You need to execute this when the DOM has loaded

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` return an array of object! not an object..

Comment: I should have specified that I'm selecting one of the elements with images[1] for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `.hasClass()` is a jQuery function. You call it on jQuery objects, not native DOM objects. The simple solution is to create a jquery object:

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('something');
var hasSomeClass = $(domElement).hasClass('some-class');
```

Of course, if you're using jQuery already, why not just do this:

```
var $images = $('img');
```

Comment: In the context of a javascript/ECMAScript forum, DOM objects are host objects, not native.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I totally forgot that I could select image elements that way for some reason. I'm guessing getElementById is a JavaScript function and therefore doesn't return the appropriate kind of object for a JQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

in jquery:

```
$("img").each(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass("className")){

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because jQuery elements are different from HTML elements. jQuery elements are special jQuery objects, and you can only run jQuery methods on these. However, you can turn an element into a jQuery object like this:

```
var images=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var jQueryImages=$(images)
```

but you can also do it directly with jQuery like this:

```
var jQueryImages=$('img');
```

And one last thing, that function does NOT return an `HTMLImageElement`. It returns a `NodeList`, as there may be more than one `img` element in the document. A `NodeList` is essentially an array of elements.